# I have an app that will not load past the splash screen on an emulator except when installed via xamarin tools from VS

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, appium, xamarin.uitest

I have tried installing this from app center and through the ADB but the result is the same.I need it to run without xamarin framework to use Appium
It can work in a xamarin project but I am switching to a different framework and now I can not get it to pass the splash screen.
I can not open the app from the emulator.

Comment: Can you explain it in a more simpler way? cant understand your question

Comment: It installs through ADB but when I click the app on the Emulator it loads the splash screen and just sits there. If I used xamarin I did not experience the issue how do I get it to go past the splash screen.

Comment: @user1622681 You mean that you have xamarin app, now you install it on emulator, you want to open it that don't pass the splash screen?

Comment: Correct the app is built through Xamarin. I now am using a .NET environment to write tests with Appium. The app will not install from an app canter or via ADB. It will install on a read device and in the past I have seen it work on Emulators that were built with in a Xamarin environment.

Comment: I recently deleted the app from the emulator believing it is not fully installed. I now see a {install_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed to parse/data/app/.601534033.tmp/base/apk. Through an adb install. through code I see a Zip format exception and through App Center I get App not installed.